# Jeditable reset() with a specific value

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I'm using jeditable 1.7.1 and what I'm trying to do is reset the form with a custom value. So for example, if the user clicks outside of the form (triggering the reset) I want to be able to set the value of the content. Something along the lines of reset("new content") or content("my custom content"). Is there a way to do this? Or will I have to modify the original source code?

I could always just set the content manually with this.html("put my new stuff here") but then it looses it's 'editable' properties.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have just to add this option: onblur: "submit".
With this option, if you click outside the form, it anyway submit the content.

Example:

```
$('.edit').editable('http://page.php', {
     onblur: "submit"
 });
```

Hope this was your problem!